# Get refund status from amazon mws order

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I am using amazon mws api for integrating orders from amazon. After i cancel an order, refund is applied on amazon seller central. How can i know the status of the refund, in the form of may be a report or something?. Because after amazon does the refund, I should also update the status on my(seller) side. Also what is the maximum number of days within  which the refund will trigger ? Plz help.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for "Settlement Reports" in Reports API which has following report types you can use.
- _GET_FLAT_FILE_PAYMENT_SETTLEMENT_DATA_
- _GET_PAYMENT_SETTLEMENT_DATA_
- _GET_ALT_FLAT_FILE_PAYMENT_SETTLEMENT_DATA_

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Does the settlement report provide the refund status against the order number? It would be very helpful if you could please post a sample report here.